# What does `argument` do in `super(argument)`?

Tags: ruby, arguments, super

I have the following code:

```
class Bicycle  
  attr_reader :gears, :wheels, :seats  
  def initialize(gears = 1, wheels = 2)  
    @gears = gears  
    @wheels = wheels
    @seats = 1  
  end  
end  

b = Bicycle.new
b.gears # => 1
b.wheels # => 2
b.seats # => 1

class Tandem < Bicycle  
  def initialize(gears)  
    super(gears)
    @seats = 2  
  end  
end  

t = Tandem.new(2)
t.gears # => 2
t.wheels # => 2
t.seats # => 2
```

and when I remove `super`, `t.gears` and `t.wheels` return `nil` as expected.

However, the code returns the same result whether I run `super(gears)` or `super`. What does `argument` in `super(argument)` do? In what case will it make a difference when I type in `super(argument)` or `super`?

Comment: Reference from the above code: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_overriding_methods.html

Comment: `super(argument)` calls the corresponding parent class' method with the given `argument`. In this specific case, it calls the parent class `initialize(argument)`. `super` with no argument, it calls the parent class method with no argument.

Comment: Does that mean if parent has `arg1, arg2, arg3`, and on child class `super(arg1, arg2)` - `arg3` will return `nil` in child class?

Comment: If child calls `super(arg1, arg2)` and parent class has `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` it won't match since the parent doesn't have a method with 2 arguments. You'll get "wrong number of arguments" error.

Comment: @lurker unless the arguments are optional, just like in the OPs code.

Comment: @Stefan yes! Sorry, missed the initializers the OP had. In that case, of course, the default argument value will be used.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the comments for this question are incorrect. Here is an accurate description of what `super` does.

If called with arguments (like above), it will pass those arguments to the overridden method in the parent class regardless of the arguments passed to the overriding method in the child class. For example:

```
class Parent
  def test(*args)
    puts "Args: #{args}"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def test(*args)
    super('hello')
  end
end

Child.new.test
'Args: [hello]'
=> ...
```

If `super` is called without any arguments, the arguments are implicitly passed from the child method. For example:

```
class Parent
  def test(*args)
    puts "Args: #{args}"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def test(*args)
    super
  end
end

Child.new.test('arg1', 'arg2')
'Args: [arg1, arg2]'
=> ...
```

Hope that clears it up!

Answer (score 1):

super by default will just send the params of the current method to the parent method.

super(arg1, arg2) will override the current method params when sending to the parent method.